# Method to return modified version of List

Tags: refactoring, dart

I'd like to know if it's possible to refactor this code into something  shorter (one line?).

```dart
List<String> get actionOutcomes {
  List result = new List();
  _actions.forEach((Action a) { result.add(a.outcome) });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [List.map](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.List#id_map) and then build a new List from the resulting Iterable:

```dart
List<String> get actionOutcomes => new List.from(_actions.map((e) => e.outcome));
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for!

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.List#id_map

Comment: Alternative without the "new": `_actions.map((e)=>e.outcome).toList()`.

Comment: Yes, the `.toList()` creates a new List from the "Lazy Iterator" returned by the `.map()`.